# Calculations in class not working

Tags: c++, function, class

This is a homework assignment and I'm pretty new at C++ but I need to calculate pay for employees. Instead of an obvious answer under $1000, it gives me a number that's negative of 1.5*10^23 or something like that. What did I do wrong? Here's what I have for code:

```
//class .cpp file
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "MyEmployee.h"
using namespace std;

MyEmployee::MyEmployee()
{
    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = 0;
    NAME = "";
    STREET_ADDRESS = "";
    PHONE_NUMBER = "";
    HOURLY_WAGE = 0;
    WEEKLY_HOURS = 0;
    GROSS_PAY = 0;
    STATE_TAX = .075;
    FEDERAL_TAX = .2;
    OVERTIME_RATE = 1.5;
    NET_PAY = 0;
    FOURTY = 40;
    OVERTIME_PAY = 0;
}


MyEmployee::MyEmployee(int e, string n, string s, string p, double h, double w)
{
    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = e;
    NAME = n;
    STREET_ADDRESS = s;
    PHONE_NUMBER = p;
    HOURLY_WAGE = h;
    WEEKLY_HOURS = w;
}

int MyEmployee::getEmployeeNumber() const
{
    return EMPLOYEE_NUMBER;
}
int MyEmployee::setEmployeeNumber(int e)
{
    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = e;
    return EMPLOYEE_NUMBER;
}
string MyEmployee::getName() const
{
    return NAME;
}
string MyEmployee::setName(string n)
{
    NAME = n;
    return NAME;
}
string MyEmployee::getStreetAddress() const
{
    return STREET_ADDRESS;
}
string MyEmployee::setStreetAddress(string s)
{
    STREET_ADDRESS = s;
    return STREET_ADDRESS;
}
string MyEmployee::getPhoneNumber() const
{
    return PHONE_NUMBER;
}
string MyEmployee::setPhoneNumber(string p)
{
    PHONE_NUMBER = p;
    return PHONE_NUMBER;
}
double MyEmployee::getHourlyWage() const
{
    return HOURLY_WAGE;
}
double MyEmployee::setHourlyWage(double h)
{
    HOURLY_WAGE = h;
    return HOURLY_WAGE;
}
double MyEmployee::getWeekHours() const
{
    return WEEKLY_HOURS;
}
double MyEmployee::setWeekHours(double w)
{
    WEEKLY_HOURS = w;
    return WEEKLY_HOURS;
}
double MyEmployee::calcPay()
{
    if (WEEKLY_HOURS > FOURTY)
    {
        OVERTIME_PAY = ((WEEKLY_HOURS - FOURTY) * HOURLY_WAGE) * OVERTIME_RATE;
        GROSS_PAY = OVERTIME_PAY + (FOURTY * HOURLY_WAGE);
        NET_PAY = GROSS_PAY - (GROSS_PAY * FEDERAL_TAX) - (GROSS_PAY * STATE_TAX);
    }
    else
    {
        GROSS_PAY = WEEKLY_HOURS * HOURLY_WAGE;
        NET_PAY = GROSS_PAY - (GROSS_PAY * FEDERAL_TAX) -(GROSS_PAY * STATE_TAX);
    }
    return NET_PAY;
}
//This is my "driver" or main code:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "MyEmployee.h"
using namespace std;

void printCheck(MyEmployee&);

int main()
{
    MyEmployee emp1(1, "Dale Nelson", "480 UVU lane, Orem, UT 84058", "801-863-8000", 10, 45);
    MyEmployee emp2(2, "John Smith", "161 South 550 East, Enterprise, Utah 84725", "801-867-5309", 12.5, 30);
    printCheck(emp1);
    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");
    printCheck(emp2);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void printCheck(MyEmployee& employ1)
{
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << "-------------------Fluff Shuffle Electronics----------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\nPay to the order of " << employ1.getName() << " ............................$" << fixed << setprecision(2) << employ1.calcPay() << endl;
    cout << "United Bank of Orem" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Hours worked: " << employ1.getWeekHours() << endl;
    cout << "Wages: $" << fixed << employ1.getHourlyWage() << endl;
}
```

Comment: What happened to the indentation bit?

Comment: Preparing a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org) is a very valuable skill, well worth learning.

Comment: Storing magic numbers such as 40 in variables which are named after the number itself, is perverse. Give it a reasonable name e.g. `hoursPerWeek`. The whole point of storing a magic number in a variable instead of using the number itself, is that it might change in the future. In a future update, `forty = 50` will make no sense, but `hoursPerWeek = 50` will (hopefully you also noticed from my example that "fourty" is not a word).

Comment: Ok, I updated it to remove as much of the redundant stuff. I probably could be less redundant, but unfortunately @chris, this is the style the teacher wants. Anyways, I would like to know why it won't give me an answer like $500 instead of -$1.5*10^123. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your weekly hours is 0 and fourty is 40. Under your first branch you have weekly_hours - fourty which will give you -40. I dont know exactly what you are looking for but you should start there

Answer (score 0):

You have two `costructors`. One with default (without any parameters) and second with parameters.

```
MyEmployee::MyEmployee()
```

Here you are setting many values to default (initializing to your desired values)

```
MyEmployee::MyEmployee(int e, string n, string s, string p, double h, double w)
```

Here you are setting only few parameters keeping all other to un-initialized aka garbage like `FOURTY`, `OVERTIME_RATE`, `FEDERAL_TAX`, `STATE_TAX` etc..

And when you create object as below, parametric constructor is getting called, keeping many things un-initized.

```
MyEmployee emp1(1, "Dale Nelson", "480 UVU lane, Orem, UT 84058", "801-863-8000", 10, 45);
```

So, initialize other variables in your `constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

Having a variable `FOURTY` whose value should be 40 is horrible. Having it as a *member* variable (as if its value could be different for each employee) is even more so (although not entirely unrealistic in software engineering). But you set its value in only *one* of the two constructors. In the constructor you *use*, it's value remains undefined, which leads to trouble.